# Does adding the 'signingkey' and setting 'gpgsign' to 'true' in the configuration enable GPG signing of commits?

Tags: git, git-commit

I've gone ahead and added the 'signingkey' and set 'gpgsign' to 'true' in the .gitconfig file. Now, I'd like to create a concise git commit message summarizing this change. However, I'm uncertain if 'Enable GPG signing of commits' would be an appropriate choice. My hesitation stems from not being entirely familiar with the process, and also because English isn't my native language. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The repo config is not tracked, it's per-repo. You can't track it with the Git history, you can't commit that.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

I hadn't realized you were just asking a language question. Yes, the phrase "Enable GPG signing of commits" is an accurate description of this process.

### Original

It seems like the easiest way to answer this question is just to write a commit message and then check after the fact whether or not it's been signed.  Let's try it.

First, we configure git:

```
$ git config --global user.email testuser@example.com
$ git config --global user.name 'Test User'
$ git config --global commit.gpgSign true
$ git config --global user.signingKey AEA805081B9DB9347DD29BA006668432A638774B
```

Then we create a test repository:

```
$ git init testrepo
```

And then we create and commit a file:

```
$ cd testrepo
$ echo hello world > testfile
$ git add testfile
$ git commit -m 'this is a test'
```

That prompted me for a passphrase, which is promising. Let's verify that the commit was signed:

```
$ git log --show-signature
commit d9d6c584f90fa8882dcefda1c5c411ba2a2ef972 (HEAD -> master)
gpg: Signature made Wed Aug 23 19:00:30 2023 UTC
gpg:                using EDDSA key AEA805081B9DB9347DD29BA006668432A638774B
gpg: Good signature from "Test User <testuser@example.com>" [ultimate]
Author: Test User <testuser@example.com>

Date:   Wed Aug 23 19:00:30 2023 +0000

    this is a test
```

Looks good!

Comment: But adding those options "commit.gpgSign"  and "user.signingKey"  I enable GPG signing? Sure I know it works, but I want to know how to refer to it if you read my original post.

Comment: I wasn't entirely clear what you were asking.

Comment: Thank you. I set the 'gpgsign' to 'true' which is "Enable GPG signing" but I also added the signingkey option. I'm not sure if "Enable" in "Enable GPG signing of commits" is okay in this situation because I not just enabled but also added the signingkey.